# Populating Tables in Access

Tags: ms-access-2013

I'm new to Access and trying to create a simple Access tool where one Table gets data from another Table.

For example I have Table 1 with a Qty for each unique ID. Table 2A now needs to retrieve data from Table 1 based on the row's ID to finally look like Table 2B.

```
    Table 1:        |   Table 2A:        |   Table 2B:
  -----------------------------------------------------------
    ID  Name    Qty |   ID  Name    Qty |   ID  Name    Qty
    1   One     19  |   1   One         |   1   One     19
    2   Two     21  |   3   Three       |   3   Three   10
    3   Three   10  |   1   One         |   1   One     19
    4   Four    26  |   4   Four        |   4   Four    26
    5   Five    20  |   4   Four        |   4   Four    26
```

I took a look at the "Lookup Wizard" but all the forums I've been to advises not to use it. Can anyone please advise on how to do this in Access in the simplest way.

Comment: Browse for a tutorial on _Beginning with SQL_ or the like.

Comment: Thank you. Read through [http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql.htm](http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql.htm) and figured out how to do it.

Comment: Great. Thanks for the feedback.